# What are the most commonly used web picture/image/icon sizes?

Tags: images, standards, photo

Similar to what already exists [regarding web banner sizes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_banner#Standard_sizes), is it possible to find the list of most commonly used picture/image/icon sizes on the web (e.g. 16x16 for small icons, 24x24 for medium icons, 50x50 to 70x50 for small profile pictures...)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no standard as icons can be of any size depending on how they're going to be used. The most common sizes I've seen based on icon sets I have downloaded are:

- 12x12
- 16x16
- 32x32
- 64x64
- 128x128
- 256x256

Do you see a pattern here?

**update**

There are no default image sizes for websites as a whole. Dimensions are dictated by how the website needs to use them. When size does matter is when you are using a third party service and have to conform to *their* standards. Examples would be gravatar sizes. But if someone wanted to use different sizes for their own blog engine they could certainly do so and wouldn't break anything or cause confusion elsewhere.

So use whatever sizes you need to use and only worry about what someone else is doing when you have to interface with their API or any form of interface that has size requirements.

Comment: Thanks but you seem to have focused on icons, what about pictures/images. I appreciate there may not be any standards hence the phrasing ("commonly used"). What would be great would be to find a table inventorying the various types of pictures/images (small profile picture, full size profile picture, news thumbnails...) and their corresponding sizes on the major websites (facebook, twitter, linkedin, youtube...)

Comment: John's answer pretty much stands; there is no common. Twitter scales your avatar to 73x73, but it's possible to view the original, whatever size it is. Here's a [Facebook image cheat sheet](http://www.dreamgrow.com/facebook-cheat-sheet-sizes-and-dimensions/), with some *weird* (from the perspective of "common") sizes. LinkedIn: 100x100 though some of that is a white border they add on. And that's just profiles for only three sites.